# Xaml style isn't applied to all buttons

Tags: xaml, uwp

In the `ItemTemplate` for an `ItemsControl` i have a couple of `ContentControl`s (a header and a footer)

in the footer i have a couple of buttons on which i have added a style, but the content property being set by the style is only applied on the buttons in the `ItemsControl`'s first item instead of all of them

the itemscontrol xaml

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              Margin="20">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="{StaticResource PostBackground}" CornerRadius="5" Margin="{StaticResource PostMargin}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource PostHeader}"/>
                <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource PostFooter}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

style for the post footer

```
<Style TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="PostFooter">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="5 0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=NotesCount, Converter={StaticResource NumberToReadableConverter}}"/>
                        <Run Text="notes"/>
                    </TextBlock>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource ReblogButton}" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="black"/>
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource LikeButton}" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="black"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and the styles for the buttons

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="LikeButton">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="&#xEB51;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
                <TextBlock Text="&#xEB52;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Foreground="Red" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Liked}" Value="True">
                            <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
                    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ReblogButton">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SymbolIcon Symbol="Switch"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and the end result looks like this
[image: end result of the xaml]

Comment: Setting the content of a control in a style that will be used by multiple controls only works if the type is something like a string or int. I'm guessing `<SymbolIcon Symbol="Switch"/>` is a control itself. If that's the case, then you're not actually instantiating the object multiple times, so only one control actually gets the content because a control can only have one direct parent.

Comment: @Meloviz i just removed symbolicon and replaced it with just text and that seem to show up in every button,
but i would still like to put those symbols in the buttons,
would it work if i put the button and the content set using the setter in a usercontrol and put those in the footer?

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own reusable custom templated control, but I only recommend doing this if you plan on having lots of toggleable icon buttons throughout your app(s) since it requires a bit of work.

**IconButton.cs**

```cs
public sealed class IconButton : ToggleButton
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CheckedContent", typeof(object), typeof(IconButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object CheckedContent
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(CheckedContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CheckedContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedForegroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CheckedForeground", typeof(Brush), typeof(IconButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public Brush CheckedForeground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(CheckedForegroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CheckedForegroundProperty, value); }
    }

    public IconButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(IconButton);
    }
}
```

**Style inside Themes\Generic.xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="local:IconButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForeground}"/>
    <Setter Property="CheckedForeground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:IconButton">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushChecked}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Glyph" Storyboard.TargetName="Icon">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding CheckedContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Icon">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding CheckedForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Glyph" Storyboard.TargetName="Icon">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding CheckedContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Icon">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding CheckedForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Glyph" Storyboard.TargetName="Icon">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding CheckedContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Icon">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding CheckedForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedDisabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Glyph" Storyboard.TargetName="Icon">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding CheckedContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Icon">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding CheckedForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushIndeterminate}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushIndeterminatePointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushIndeterminatePressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminateDisabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushIndeterminateDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Grid x:Name="InnerGrid" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <FontIcon x:Name="Icon" Glyph="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can use it like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <local:IconButton Content="&#xEB51;" CheckedContent="&#xEB52;" CheckedForeground="Red"/>
    <local:IconButton Content="&#xE8EB;" CheckedContent="&#xE8EB;" CheckedForeground="LimeGreen"/>
</StackPanel>
```

[image: Screenshot]

(I've set the border and background to transparent in the default style so that it looks less like a traditional button, but you can change it to whatever you want.)